# How can you film a woman giving birth when the camera angle has not shifted?

Tags: film-techniques

In **Big Momma's House**(2000) we see a woman giving birth to a baby.

The camera angle does not shift at all during the scene, or very little at least and a baby is filmed coming *out* of the woman.

**In movies like this, how is a woman giving birth to a live baby filmed when the camera angle has not shifted at all?**

Comment: Is there anyway I can get rid of this question, I feel like it isn't any good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is the clip you're talking about:

1. Your assertion that the camera angle does not shift at all is wrong.  There's several dozen jump-cuts and camera angles there.
2. We don't actually see the baby coming out of the woman at all.  There's a bunch of cuts and people yelling, then someone's holding a baby.  We never actually see it emerge.

So I think your memory of the film may be a bit off.  I think you're remembering things that were only implied.

Comment: Yeah, that would be probably true actually, thanks for the heads up about that :)